# Should i update ubuntu 12.04 iso image to 14.04 iso image using zsync?

Tags: iso, zsync

Can I do this by just renaming the previous iso? or what?

Comment: You can download ubuntu 14.04 beta from http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ and the daily iso from herehttp://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/ algo please notice that support questions about ubuntu 14.04 are offtopic as it is not yet officialy released.

Comment: Thanks xangua, I know there are beta releases but I want to know if zsync can update an older version iso to a newer version of iso or not, I don't need support or help on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

That's not a good idea. It's better to wait until tomorrow April 17 and download the Ubuntu 14.04 final release (update: Ubuntu 14.04 final release is now available for download). By the time you figure out how to update your Ubuntu 12.04 iso and make it work as an Ubuntu 14.04 iso, it will probably be April 17 anyway, and you will be able to download the final release of Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Thanks Karel, I just want to know that can zsync do that? can it update an oler iso of different version to latest version? I will surely gonna wait till tomorrow's release.

Comment: [Updating Ubuntu Boot CD Images with zsync](http://digitivity.org/938/updating-ubuntu-boot-cd-iso-images-with-zsync-incremental-download). The tutorial focuses on updating daily builds rather than updating an iso to an entirely different release which resembles building a house of cards.

Comment: Ya that's why I put up the question. Does someone know if it will work or not?

Comment: That's like asking if you could ride a dog. In the limiting case if there was a very well trained large enough dog and a small enough child, possibly yes. But in the general case, no, it would be better to put a saddle on a horse and ride that. But if your question is strictly like "can you ride a dog?" leaving aside the issue of cruelty then possibly yes.

Comment: "zsync downloads only the new parts of the file." Source http://zsync.moria.org.uk/
It is more like riding a bull and I don't think there is even a slight shadow of cruelty.